# Update specific attributes on a Core Data entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data

While updating a record in an entity, is there any way to keep an attribute as immutable, i.e. I would like to update all other attribute values except a particular attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can.

Update only the attributes you are interested in and do a `save`. The keys you don't touch will not be updated.

Suppose you have an entity with two attributes: `attribute1` and `attribute2`.

If you modify `attribute2` and perform a `save`, `attribute1` will remain as before.

```
[yourObj setValue:@"SOME_NEW_VALUE" forKey:@"attribute2"];
```

or

```
yourObj.attribute2 = @"SOME_NEW_VALUE";
```

if you have created subclasses for your entities.

But, my question is: are you trying to achieve something specific?

Comment: yes...In my entity I have 2 attributes namely Id ,Name.I get only Name attribute value from the rest response json file.Id value is locally maintained. Im getting this json response periodically.So when i periodically map this core data entity, will my Id value get replaced with null value?

Comment: @JamesDon no. And if you don't update it, nothing will happen...`id` is not a good name to give to an attribute. I would prefer `identifier` or `guid`.

Comment: thnkss for reply and suggestion. It really saved my time.

Comment: @JamesDon you should Check the gray mark positioned to the left of the answer. It will become green.